# Patchin a car file made for ESB WSO2

Tags: packaging, wso2, wso2-esb

I have build a car "carbon" file for a ESB WSO2 server, what i want to do now is to patch the car file and update an existing sequence into it!
I know in JAVA you can do this using "jar uf foo.jar foo.class"   form "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jar.html"
is this possible for Car files too ? 
the idea is to override the already existing sequence inside!

Comment: AFAIK overriding is not possible. If its a simple content change in a existing sequence you could open the car with compression tool, open the sequence and put in the change.

Comment: I need to do it through command line ... it is possible? If yes can you give me an example??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following,

```
mv YOUR_CAR.car YOUR_CAR.zip
zip -u YOUR_CAR.zip <file to update>
mv YOUR_CAR.zip YOUR_CAR.car
```